# nested JSON object not mapping to server side Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm trying to send a JSON string to a controller using an AJAX call.  Everything seems to be working fine except for the nested object within the JSON string is not mapping to the nested object on the controller side.  Here's an example of my code.

```
Class MyClass1{
    string prop1;
    string prop2;
    string prop3;
    MyClass2 prop4;
}

Class MyClass2{
    string prop5;
    string prop6;
    string prop7;
}
```

and here's how I'm trying to map.

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("Member", "Application")',
                data: { applicantModel:getAppData(), buttonText: $("#btnSave").val(), isDeleted: $("#hdnDeleted").val() },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {

                }
            });
        })

getAppData = function () {
        var fields = {
    "prop1": "a",
    "prop2": "b",
    "prop3": "c",
    "prop4":{
        "prop5": "d",
        "prop6": "e",
        "prop7": "f"
        }
    }

    return fields;
}
```

and my controller method...

```
<HttpPost()>
    Function Member(applicantModel As ApplicantModels, buttonText as String, isDeleted as String) As ActionResult
       //do some stuff with the data
       Return View(applicantModel)
    End Function
```

When I break inside the controller, my object for MyClass1 is mapped correctly but the prop4 data is not mapped.  I have tried several ideas from other threads, I have tried to JSON.Stringify() the JSON before sending it in the Ajax call.  I am completely out of ideas.  Would love some help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post how you are instantiating your payload and sending it across the wire.

Comment: Updated with more code

Comment: I don't think you need to quote the property names in the getAppData function, the values yes, but not the prop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your view model properties `public` with `set` and `get` accessors, so that the DefaultModel binder can set the values of these properties from the form data posted.

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
    public MyClass2 prop4 { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass2
{
    public string prop5 { get; set; }
    public string prop6 { get; set; }
    public string prop7{ get; set; }
}
```

With this change, your code should work fine.

Comment: I did try that, added the contentType="application/json" and still didn't get the fields mapped properly.  I didn't set it to var m, but I did do data: JSON.stringify({ applicantModel:getAppData(), buttonText: $("#btnSave").val(), isDeleted: $("#hdnDeleted").val() }).  Is this wrong?

Comment: how does your action method looks like ?

Comment: I've added the basics of the method to my code.  if I break on the very first line of the method, applicantModel is populated with all the data except from the inner object (prop4 in my pseudo code)

Comment: I copied and pasted the code in the answer and it worked fine. What you mean by it does not work ! Which part ?

Comment: I created a brand new project and tried it with very simple logic and it worked perfectly.  There must be something in the existing project that is preventing it.  I guess I will have to look into that more, it appears your help was correct and there's something else happening.  Thanks!